# xslt:fo Page-number not working

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

This is a newbie question for xslt 1.0 FO

My requirement:
Print the page number as footer on each page

I followed this template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>

<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
  <fo:layout-master-set>
    <fo:simple-page-master master-name="my-page">
      <fo:region-body margin="1in"/>
    </fo:simple-page-master>
  </fo:layout-master-set>

  <fo:page-sequence master-reference="my-page">
    <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-before">
  <fo:block text-align="end">
    Page <fo:page-number/>
    of <fo:page-number-citation ref-id="terminator"/>
  </fo:block>
</fo:static-content>
    <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
      <fo:block>Hello, world!</fo:block>
    </fo:flow>

  </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
```

I expect to see page number at the top of each page (even if its just 1 page)
But all I see is

> Page of Hello, world!

How do I correct my xslt for showing the page number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: You have not defined any region-before in your page-master.

```
 <fo:simple-page-master master-name="my-page">
        <fo:region-body margin="1in"/>
        <fo:region-before extent="1in"/>
 </fo:simple-page-master>
```

Now you have a region to place that content.

Next, this:

```
<fo:page-number-citation ref-id="terminator"/>
```

Will never work unless you have some "id" in your document named "terminator". Below is a complete example.

```
    <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
        <fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:simple-page-master master-name="my-page">
                <fo:region-body margin="1in"/>
                <fo:region-before extent="1in"/>
            </fo:simple-page-master>
        </fo:layout-master-set>

        <fo:page-sequence master-reference="my-page">
            <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-before">
                <fo:block text-align="end">
                    Page <fo:page-number/>
                    of <fo:page-number-citation ref-id="terminator"/>
                </fo:block>
            </fo:static-content>
            <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                <fo:block>Hello, world!</fo:block>
                <fo:block id="terminator"></fo:block>
            </fo:flow>

        </fo:page-sequence>
    </fo:root>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.
 I tried the sample code in your reply but still I see only "Page of Hello, world!"
 There are no page numbers visible
 
 Steps:
 I copied the sample code from your reply into an xslt
 Created a simple XML which referred to the xslt above
 browsed the XML from internet explorer 8
 
 Am I missing any other step?

Comment: You are using XSL FO. It requires an XSL FO publishing engine to produce print output. This is not a browser. And it requires no XML at all as you do not have an XSL-T, you have an XSL FO file. Are you expecting a browser to interpret XSL FO and create a PDF automatically?

Comment: If you are trying to create print from browser, go here for a sample:

http://www.cloudformatter.com/Nimbus.Editor?http://cdn.xportability.com/Samples/ProgressReport.html

Select "Toggle View" and you have see more of the logic and such, including page X of Y type pages. Click "Generate" and this would create an XSL that would take that XML in the tree and make XSL FO for print. You can also click "Preview" which prints it. You can use that site with your XML to make XSL for print including page numbering.

Comment: My bad, I did not know about the XSL FO rendering.
my expectation is, I need to print the page numbers at the end of an xml when it is browsed using IE8.0

Comment: OK. Yes, not XSL FO ... and not possible ... as there are no "pages".

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I will check for other options.